# Typescript how to address native interface

Tags: typescript

There is a native `File` interface in typescript
[image]

Let's say I have a custom class/interface called `File`

```
class File {
  read(input: File) {}
}
```

How do I tell typescript that the type of `input` parameter is native typescript's `File` implementation and not my own?

Comment: I imagine you can use namespaces to separate them, but im not sure if that works or if there is a better answer(s).

Comment: Is your custom `File` class in a module or namespace already?  If not you'll get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your custom class within a [namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#namespacing).  [Angularjs type definitions does this with the `ng.` prefix](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular/index.d.ts#L23). That way if you want an angularjs type you have to use `ng`.

In the same way you can put your custom type in a namespace so that `myCustom.File` refers to your copy and just `File`.

```
namespace myCustom {
    class File {
      read(input: File) {}
    }
}
```

Or export the class definitions into a namespace as angularjs type definitions have.

Im not sure if this will work as is but if not then you could export the builtin type into a namespace and reference it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If your class is in the global scope you will get a compiler error trying to redefine the type named `File`:

```
class File { } // error!
//    ~~~~ <--- Duplicate identifier 'File'.
```

which makes sense because you already have a constructor value and an interface named `File` in scope.

So I'm going to assume your class is instead in its own module, say in a file named **`myModule.ts`**:

```
// myModule.ts
export class File {
  read(input: File) { // does not work yet
  }
}
```

But of course, inside `myModule.ts` the type named `File` refers to your new class's instances, and not to global `File` interface.  How can we fix that?

If you are using TypeScript 3.4 or higher, you can make use of the [`globalThis` namespace](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis):

```
// myModule.ts
export class File {
  read(input: globalThis.File) { // okay now
  }
}
```

And let's make sure it works:

```
const file = new File();
const globalFile = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].files!.item(0)!

file.read(file); // error!
file.read(globalFile); // okay!
```

Looks good!

[Playground Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DECWThwDeAUHGXFMCgCYAUOAdmAK4wBccA5khAEYpIAKgAscaAHS58ASiKlyAX2JLiCCAzTwAZngIBeOA2AB3bLtrSA3KvWauPfkin641CAmYBbYAxjjOwDAAovjevmgAQgCegiicAHIo3rQARIwsMCnSANoADAC64jr4aACE4jgwwJ60udKlxMTFwOKUNLTNVnAA9N1wwFBQ0A3NrVR03HwCzl29cBAA1ihRpUA)

---

If you don't have a `globalThis` namespace because you're using an older version of TypeScript, the only way I can think of to do this is to add a new global type named, say, `GlobalFile` which is a type alias for the global `File` interface.  And you have to do this in a file outside your module in global scope, say in a file named **`outsideMyModule.ts`**:

```
// outsideMyModule.ts
type GlobalFile = File; // no export, so not a module
```

Then, inside **`myModule.ts`** you can use the type alias instead:

```
export class File {
  read(input: GlobalFile) { // okay now
  }
}
```

which should work the same way as before:

```
const file = new File();
const globalFile = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].files!.item(0)!

file.read(file); // error!
file.read(globalFile); // okay!
```

---

Okay, hope this helps; good luck!